# Is there a way to insert values inside DB::raw? Laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have a products table which has a column named quantity. I also have a pivot table named member_product which has a quantity column as well.

I want to be able to subtract quantity from the products table with the quantity from member_product table.

Similar with updating the quantity of an inventory with the member_product as the cart. I can't seem to figure it out.

```
Tables  
products  
id | name | quantity  

member_product  
product_id | member_id | quantity
```

view

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
@foreach($members->products as $p)
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="productid[]" value="{{$p->id}}">{{$p->name}}</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="qty[]" value="{{$p->pivot->qty}}">{{$p->pivot->qty}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
@endforeach
</table>
```

controller

```
public function updateProduct(Request $request)
{

$productid = $request['productid'];
$qty     = $request['qty'];

products = DB::table('products')
      ->whereIn('id', $productid)
      ->update(['qty' => DB::raw('qty - 1')]);
      //->update(['qty' => DB::raw('qty - $qty]); (i want to execute something like this)
}
```

With my current code, i got the needed ids and can also run the `db::raw('qty -1')`.

Is it possible to insert a value inside `db::raw` so it will use the qty of the ids specified by my whereIn, which is from my product_member table. Or am i approaching this the wrong way.

I'm having a hard time dealing with arrays so please bear with me.

Comment: `->update(['qty' => DB::raw('qty - ' . (int) $qty)]);`

Comment: @Marvelln i tried it, but it only deducted 1 from the quantity instead of 3 from my $qty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Try to do this in this way

```
public function updateProduct()
{

$productid = $request['productid'];
$qty     = $request['qty'];

products = DB::table('products')
      ->join('member_product','member_product.product_id','=','products.id')
      ->whereIn('products.id', $productid)
      ->update(['products.quantity' => DB::raw("products.quantity - member_product.quantity")]);
}
```

You need to use table names before field names to avoid ambiguous column names in query.

Comment: It's not exact solution. It's just the advice how you can handle substracting two different values from two different tables in one query update. 

In which line has error raised?

Comment: Thank you its working!! And it's working as i wanted it to do. I had to change ->whereIn('product.id, $productid) to ->whereIn('id', $productid) as it could not locate product.id. Nevertheless accepted as answer thank you again.

Comment: Yes, I made mistake with table name. It should be products instead of product. Glad I could have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be to define a belongsToMany on the member and then update as follows...

```
Member::find(1)->products()->updateExistingPivot($productId, [
    'qty' => 1
]);
```

You will of course need to update your product qty also.

Comment: i see ill remember this method for my future projects. I'm still new to laravel so ill have to stick to what i know for now. Thank you for the advice.